# apache tries to access .htaccess in lost+found directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, file-permissions

A subdirectory `/var/www/vhost/servername/httpdocs/subdir/`of an apache (ver. 2.2.22 on ubuntu 12.04) vhost webroot is a disk partition of its own. Accordingly, there is also `/var/www/vhost/servername/httpdocs/subdir/lost+found`. In my apache error logs I find errors that `/var/www/vhost/servername/httpdocs/subdir/lost+found/.htaccess` cannot be read, with a referer like `/var/www/vhost/servername/httpdocs/subdir/foo/` (i.e. when a `FancyIndexing` directory index of that dirctory is displayed to the user).

> [Fri Nov 28 09:14:19 2014] [crit] [client 10.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/vhost/servername/httpdocs/subdir/lost+found/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer: `http://servername/subdir/foo/`

I cannot make sense of this. Why would apache try to read

- `/var/www/vhost/servername/httpdocs/subdir/lost+found/.htaccess`

on that occasion? In my understanding it should only have reason to try to read

- `/var/www/vhost/servername/httpdocs/subdir/foo/.htaccess`
- `/var/www/vhost/servername/httpdocs/subdir/.htaccess`
- `/var/www/vhost/servername/httpdocs/.htaccess`

Interestingly, no corresponding error messages occur with deeper subdirectories (e.g. `http://servername/subdir/foo/bar/baz/`).

What causes this error (or the read attempt in the first place)? And how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache will try to find `.htaccess` files in every  directory, but `lost+found` is usually readable by `root` only, so it can't even check if a file is there.

One solution is to mount the disk somewhere else, move the data into a subdir of that mountpoint and then either symlink or bind-mount that subdir it into place. This way, `lost+found` isn't in the directory tree Apache searches.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the word "every"? I presume it will never try that outside the docroot, to begin with. Would it want to check `(webroot)/bar/bar/bar/.htaccess` to display `(webroot)/foo/foo/foo/`?

Comment: Now I see: The *referer* in the log entry is not the page generating the error. Instead, it is the page from where we came to the page that generated the error - the page generating the error is not mentioened in the error log entry. And in fact the error ws generated when going to the "Parent directory" from a subdirectory (which explains why no deeper directories occur in the error.log). In that case, apache checks if (and how) it shold display `lost+found`. Instead of moving the data around as Sven suggested, an additional line `IndexIgnore lost+found` helped as well.

Comment: ... and performance-wise, Sven's suggestion is certainly better.